# Querying Line Items of Order with JSON Functions in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am banging my head head here for the past 2 hours with all the available JSON_... functions in BigQuery. I've read quite a few questions here but no matter why I try, I never succeed in extracting the "amounts" from my JSON below.

This is my JSON stored in a BQ column:

```json
                {
                    "lines": [
                        {
                            "id": "70223039-83d6-463d-a482-7ce4d50bf0fc",
                            "charges": [
                                {
                                    "type": "price",
                                    "amount": 50.0
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "discount",
                                    "amount": -40.00
                                }
                            ]
                        },

                             {
                            "id": "70223039-83d6-463d-a482-7ce4d50bf0fc",
                            "charges": [
                                {
                                    "type": "price",
                                    "amount": 20.00
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "discount",
                                    "amount": 0.00
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Imagine the above being an order containing multiple items.

I am trying to get a sum of all amounts => 50-40+20+0. The result needs to be **30** = the total order price.

Is it possible to pull all the amount values and then have them summed up just via SQL without any custom JS functions? I guess the summing is the easy part - getting the amounts into an array is the challenge here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select (
    select sum(cast(json_value(charge, '$.amount') as float64))
    from unnest(json_extract_array(order_as_json, '$.lines')) line,
    unnest(json_extract_array(line, '$.charges')) charge
  ) total
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Comment: You are THE MAN. As always. Thanks!